# Idiopathic Error C2512

Tags: visual-c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know this has been asked a million times, and I have gone through those million answers none seem to apply to my case.

I have a custom class called `CFCConnections`. I am trying to allocate memory to a pointer of this type here:

```
CFCConnections* f_pConn ;
f_pConn= new CFCConnections;
```

But I get the C2512 error. I have a default constructor, but it does nothing as it does not have to do anything. This was just written so that I could learn dynamic memory allocation.

The class file:

```
CFCConnections::CFCConnections(QObject* parent) : CResourceItem(parent)
{
    //Should I add something here? I don't want it to do anything in particular


}
CFCConnections::~CFCConnections()
{

}
```

All the include files are there, and the headers have been created.
I apologise in advance if this is a stupid question. I am not trying to get the community to solve my problems, I am just looking for anyone to point me in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

It was a silly oversight. The constructor was defined with a pointer as the input argument. When I tried to do `f_pConn= new CFCConnections;` it tried to find a constructor that took no arguments. That's why the error happened.

Changing it to `f_pConn= new CFCConnections(this);` fixed everything.

I hope this helps someone, that is why I did not delete the question